# How to upload iOS app to Appstore which uses OpenCV

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, opencv

I'm current developing iOS apps with OpenCV.
But When I want to upload app to app store it occurs error like this `Missing 64 bit support, iOS apps submitted to App Store must include 64 bit support and be built with iOS 8 SDK or later.`

But as I know, OpenCV doesn't support 64 bit (ARM 64).
And it occurs error when I changed architecture setting (add ARM 64) in build settings like `Exit With Code 1`

My concern is that how can I upload app to app store which uses OpenCV which doesn't support 64 bit version.
Thanks.

Comment: Also http://answers.opencv.org/question/81003/opencv-31-issue-on-ios9-arm64/

Comment: @RichardCritten Hi, I tried with the latest version. But it occurs error like this. `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_MW_exitHandler", referenced from:
      -[BackgroundObject stopBackground] in BackgroundObject.o`